# PDO INSERT INTO [No error in BindingParam but no data is sent to the database

Tags: php, pdo, insert-into

```
$sqlPickInsert = "INSERT INTO record_pickup(pickup_id, order_code, customer_id,
                                s_date, r_date, payment_amount, payment_mode, 
                                pickup_comments, branch, order_status) 
                               VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    echo "$sqlPickInsert <br>"; 
    echo "pickupID $nullvalues" ."<br>";
    echo "ordercode $newPickupCode" ."<br>";
    echo "customer ID $finalexistCustID" ."<br>";
    echo "loginDate $login_Date" ."<br>";
    echo "pickup $finalpick_date" ."<br>";
    echo "amount $newExpenditures" ."<br>";
    echo "paymode $paymentMode" ."<br>";
    echo "notes$finalpick_notes" ."<br>";
    echo "login branch$login_Branch" ."<br>";
    echo "status $nullvalues" ."<br>";

    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sqlPickInsert);
    if (!$stmt) die ('prepare() failed!');

    $checkID = $stmt1->bindParam(1, $nullvalues,PDO::PARAM_INT); //id
    if (!$checkID) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkCODE=$stmt1->bindParam(2, $newPickupCode,PDO::PARAM_STR);//ordercode
    if (!$checkCODE) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkCUSTID= $stmt1->bindParam(3, $finalexistCustID,PDO::PARAM_STR);//customerid
    if (!$checkCUSTID) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkSDATE=$stmt1->bindParam(4, $login_Date,PDO::PARAM_STR);//s_date
    if (!$checkSDATE) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkRDATE=$stmt1->bindParam(5, $finalpick_date,PDO::PARAM_STR);//r_date
    if (!$checkRDATE) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkAMOUNT=$stmt1->bindParam(6, $newExpenditures,PDO::PARAM_STR);//amount
    if (!$checkAMOUNT) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkPAYMODE=$stmt1->bindParam(7, $paymentMode,PDO::PARAM_STR);//paymode
    if (!$checkPAYMODE) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkNOTE=$stmt1->bindParam(8, $finalpick_notes,PDO::PARAM_STR);//note
    if (!$checkNOTE) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkBRANCH=$stmt1->bindParam(9, $login_Branch,PDO::PARAM_STR);//branch
    if (!$checkBRANCH) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $checkSTATUS=$stmt1->bindParam(10, $nullvalues,PDO::PARAM_STR);//status
    if (!$checkSTATUS) die ('bindParam() ID failed!<br>');

    $stmt1->execute();
```

Sorry for just learning PDO, I am here to learn more regarding a problem I have encountered regarding INSERT into in this specific query. I can't find where did the code went wrong. Since my other query with bindparams INSERT into is working. Did I missed something out? All variables are showing the correct information. I don't get it why this doesn't work.

[image: SS of Database]

Comment: Any errors being thrown? chuck this at the top of your php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: As pickup_id is an auto increment column, you can just miss it out of your insert.  Not sure what `$nullvalues` is.

Comment: `NULL` isn't allowed for `order_status`.

Comment: If you checked the result of `execute()` you would have seen the error.

Comment: With PDO, I recommend enabling exceptions instead of checking the result of each call.

Comment: This code is a nightmare syntax wise to future developers that will see your code, especially considering the whole thing could be narrowed down to 2-3 lines probably.

Comment: Just went back to see your answers. I just kept going with other TODO list.Thanks! for pointing out that the DB that was sent to me doesn't accept NULL values. 

Sorry for the messy code, I tried to just copy paste each one since I am frustated and I'm just starting out in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code instead:

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sqlPickInsert);

$params = [
  $nullvalues,
  $newPickupCode,
  $finalexistCustID,
  $login_Date,
  $finalpick_date,
  $newExpenditures,
  $paymentMode,
  $finalpick_notes,
  $login_Branch,
  $nullvalues
];

$stmt1->execute($params);
```

Passing an array of values to `execute()` is easier than all those `bindParam()` calls. I don't know where so many PHP developers get the idea that `bindParam()` is necessary.

Enabling ERRMODE_EXCEPTION is easier than writing checks after every call to a PDO function. this ensures that you will get an error automatically (an exception actually) if anything goes wrong during prepare or execute.

As @Barmar commented, you will probably discover that the error on `execute()` is that you seem to be passing a NULL to `order_status`, but that column doesn't accept NULLs.

At least we guess that `$nullvalues` has the value `NULL`, but you haven't said so.

Comment: thanks for this tips! I learned my lesson check the DB completely. I was frustrated and it is already midnight when I tried to this code.
I